STM32CubeIDE UART2 Status: Partly disabled conflict with PA mapped with GPIO_Output
I am trying to understand how STM32Cube ide works. I guess by default UART2 has set as UART_TX - PA2, UART_RX - PA3. I have reconfigured PA1 and PA2 as GPIO_OutPut and set UART_TX - PA14 and UART_RX - PA15. There is a yellow warning sign beside UART2 that says, 'UART2 Partly disa bled conflict with PA mapped with GPIO_Output'
I want to activate RS458 on controller startup so that I can use it with the Nvidia Jetson Orin Nano Devkit.
The debug UART of the NVIDIA Jetson Orin Nano (UART2) is routed to the RS485 transmitter on the connector board. This transmitter is disabled by default (circuit design), so it is neccessary to activate the transmitter before the NVIDIA Jetson boots to make sure that there is no loss of data/information during boot process of the NVIDIA Jetson.
To activate the RS485 transmitter, the I2C-PortExpander on the connector board must be configured accordingly.
In that case, can I continue to use the new configuration? Anyone has experienced working like this ?
